# How to get value of last attribute in a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Not very proficient with SQL. I am trying to get username, count number of login attempts and the last date of login attempt from a database table. The table schema is something like this:

```
username character varying,
logindate timestamp,
result character varying,
clientip character varying
```

I was able to get the username and number of attempts from the following query:

```
SELECT USERNAME, COUNT(USERNAME) FROM LOGINTABLE GROUP BY USERNAME
```

Is it possible to get the date for last login from the same query? Please advice.

DB Used: POSTGRESQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, use `MAX()`

```
SELECT  USERNAME, 
        COUNT(USERNAME) AS TotalCount, 
        MAX(logindate) AS LastLoginDate
FROM    LOGINTABLE 
GROUP   BY USERNAME
```